# How much space Views occupy in the RAM in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have to use Views in MongoDB v3.4.1 (MongoDB often upgraded to latest version).

I have two choices to create an ultimate view.

1. I can create a complex View directly. In this case I should create only one view.
2. I can create 3 views. The first two of these are needed to reach the third ultimate view. In this case views would be more readable, easily controllable.

However, the views will be created by using high-volume collections.

Because of the above situation I wonder that how much space is occupied by Views in the RAM. Is it equal with collections or much more less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the small amount of metadata used to define the views they don't consume any memory by themselves.

When you perform a query on a view it will fetch the relevant collection data, and *that* in turn could require the storage engine to bring more data into RAM, if the data in question was just on disk until then.

```
// Example view creation
db.runCommand ( {
   create: "managementFeedback",
   viewOn: "survey",
   pipeline: [ { $project: { "management": "$feedback.management", department: 1 } } ]
} )
// ---------
db.managementFeedback.find() //Will bring a certain amount of document data into memory, if it wasn't already there.
db.survey.aggregate([ { $project: { "management": "$feedback.management", department: 1 } } ]) //Will bring exactly the same document data into memory
```

But that is all as intended. Using the view is no more or less memory-consuming than running an aggregate command with the same pipeline.

Comment: Thank you so much! So I should only consider that a view that consists of two or more collections mean two or more query on MongoDB, simply. The most important things about Views, using index for Lookup foreign field on its own collection and query counts which performs by the view. Am I right? What do you think about?

Comment: A view that sources two collections can only be done with an aggregation that uses the $lookup operation - mongodb doesn't support classic joins - but yes that will mean two collections are read from. And yes you're right it's crucial not to forget to index the foreign field in the foreign collection - miss that and you'll be doing full collection scans of the foreign collection each time.